# Ionic 3 typescript cordova DateTimePicker code running in reverse

Tags: javascript, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, datepicker

For school we have to make a working thermostat app (it's about the design but still it needs to be able to interact with a server). We decided to do this in ionic 3. And I've had far from a smooth road so far but this issue is really really getting to me. For picking a certain on and off time (you need to be able to set multiple). I'm using the standard DatePicker but the code from it seems to be running in reverse.. And I'm clueless as to who the hell it is doing so.

The full code is below but the function I'm having trouble with is `setNewTime()` this seems to be running in reverse.. Right now the function looks like this:

```
setNewTime() {
this.newTimes = [];
this.timePicker('Day');
this.timePicker('Night');
console.log(this.newTimes);
}
```

Now the strange this is, when clicking the button that runs this function. First it will log an empty newTimes, after it will ask for a Night Time with the time picker and after that it will ask for a Day time.. Which in my opinion is really weird. First I had two separate timePicker functions. One for day and one for night but those had exactly the same behavior. The rest of my code seems to be running just fine and way I intended it too but this is piece is having it's own ideas it seems.

Would anyone be able to help me out here?

Ruben

Full code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePicker } from '@ionic-native/date-picker';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { API } from '../../api';
import { ActionSheetController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-monday',
  templateUrl: 'monday.html'
})
export class MondayPage {

  // Variables for get and put
  public day : string = 'day';
  public current_day : string = 'current_day';
  public time : string = 'time';
  public weekProgramState : string = 'weekProgramState';
  public currentTemperature : string = 'currentTemperature';
  public current_temperature : string = 'current_temperature';
  public targetTemperature : string = 'targetTemperature';
  public target_temperature : string = 'target_temperature';
  public dayTemperature : string = 'dayTemperature';
  public day_temperature : string = 'day_temperature';
  public nightTemperature : string = 'nightTemperature';
  public night_temperature : string = 'night_temperature';

  // Arrays for pushing the data
  newTimes: any = [];
  currentPeriods: any = [];
  sparePeriods: any = [];

  constructor(
    private datePicker: DatePicker,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public api: API,
    public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController
  ) {
    this.getPeriods();
  }

  // Add a new time to the schedule
  setNewTime() {
    this.newTimes = [];
    this.timePicker('Day');
    this.timePicker('Night');
    console.log(this.newTimes);
  }

  // Timepicker that lets you set the time
  timePicker(time) {
    this.datePicker.show({
      date: new Date(),
      mode: 'time',
      //titleText: 'Please pick a ' + time + ' time',
      okText: 'Set ' + time + ' time',
      minuteInterval: 5,
      is24Hour: true,
      androidTheme: 16974393
    }).then(
      date => {
        let minutes = date.getMinutes();
        let hours = date.getHours();
        let time : string;

        if ( hours < 10 ) {
          time = '0' + String(hours);
        } else {
          time = String(hours);
        }

        if ( minutes < 10 ) {
          time = time + ':0' + String(minutes);
        } else {
          time = time + ':' + String(minutes);
        }

        //console.log(time)

        this.newTimes.push(time);
        console.log(this.newTimes)
      },
      err => this.alert(err) //this.newTimes.push(err)
    );
  }

  // Makes sure the times are for format 00:00
  setTime(date) {
    let minutes = date.getMinutes();
    let hours = date.getHours();
    let time : string;

    if ( hours < 10 ) {
      time = '0' + String(hours);
    } else {
      time = String(hours);
    }

    if ( minutes < 10 ) {
      time = time + ':0' + String(minutes);
    } else {
      time = time + ':' + String(minutes);
    }

    console.log(time)

    this.newTimes.push(time);
  }

  // Push an alert out
  alert(typeOfAlert : string) {
    let cancel: string = 'CANCEL';
    if (typeOfAlert == cancel) {
      return;
    } else {
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Error occured!',
        subTitle: 'For some reason an error occured while picking the time. Please try again!',
        buttons: ['OK']
      });
      alert.present();
    }
  }

  // Options for a set time period (change, delete)
  optionsPeriod(id) {
    let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
      title: 'Modify this time period',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Change',
          handler: () => {
            //this.newTimes = [];
            this.timePicker('night');
            this.timePicker('day');
            this.removeTimePeriod('Monday', this.currentPeriods.indexOf(id));
            this.addTimePeriod('Monday', this.newTimes[0], this.newTimes[1]);
          }
        },{
          text: 'Delete',
          handler: () => {
            this.removeTimePeriod('Monday', this.currentPeriods.indexOf(id));
          }
        },{
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    actionSheet.present();
  }

  // Get data from the server
  getServer(tag) {
    return this.api.get(tag);
  }

  // Push data to the server
  putServer(tag, xmlTag, value) {
    this.api.put(tag, xmlTag, value);
  }

  // Add a time period
  addTimePeriod(day, start, end) {
    this.api.addPeriod(day, start, end);
  }

  // Remove a time period
  removeTimePeriod(day, id) {
    this.api.removePeriod(day, id);
  }

  // Gets the current periods and adds empty ones depending on that number.
  getPeriods() {
    this.currentPeriods = [];
    this.sparePeriods = [];
    this.currentPeriods = this.api.getWeekProgram().Monday;
    for(var i = 0; i < (5 - this.currentPeriods.length); i++) {
      this.sparePeriods.push(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is expected because of the asynchronous nature of the function `datePicker.show()` and by extention your function `timePicker()`.

Notice the `.then` part. This means that `datePicker.show()` returns a Promise that a value will be resolved and returned in the future. *When* that happens, the then part will be executed asynchronously, but until then it is added to what is called the `Event Queue`. You can learn more about all these interesting stuff in the video [What the heck is the event loop anyway?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ).

So what actually happens is each time you call `timePicker()` the `.then()` parts of the datePicker.show() pile up in the event queue waiting to be executed when the browser's javacript engine has nothing else to do.

The way you should go ensuring it all runs smoothly is to either call `timePicker('Day')` and inside it's then() function call `timePicker('Night')`. But to do all that, `timePicker()` needs to return a promise.

So we could change your code to something like this:

```
// Timepicker that lets you set the time
  timePicker(time) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject)  => { // notice I'm wrapping your code with a return of a new Promise
        this.datePicker.show({
        date: new Date(),
        mode: 'time',
        //titleText: 'Please pick a ' + time + ' time',
        okText: 'Set ' + time + ' time',
        minuteInterval: 5,
        is24Hour: true,
        androidTheme: 16974393
        }).then(
        date => {
            let minutes = date.getMinutes();
            let hours = date.getHours();
            let time : string;

            if ( hours < 10 ) {
            time = '0' + String(hours);
            } else {
            time = String(hours);
            }

            if ( minutes < 10 ) {
            time = time + ':0' + String(minutes);
            } else {
            time = time + ':' + String(minutes);
            }

            //console.log(time)

            this.newTimes.push(time);
            console.log(this.newTimes)
        },
        err => window.alert(err) //this.newTimes.push(err)
        );
    });
  }
```

And then we can chain the asynchronous function calls like this:

```
  // Add a new time to the schedule
  setNewTime() {
    this.newTimes = [];
    this.timePicker('Day')
        .then(() => {
            this.timePicker('Night')
                .then(() => {
                    console.log(this.newTimes);
                });
        });
  }
```

It's awesome that your school teaches with cool coding exercises like this, and even more so that you are using modern frameworks like Ionic and Angular. Keep it up!

Comment: Hey thanks for finding me again!! I tried your solution but it only shows the timepicker for day now ;/. I read up on the promises and they're still a bit vague but I feel like I'm starting to grasp the concept. I found [this site](http://www.datchley.name/promise-patterns-anti-patterns/) and tried some of the things they're saying but it's not working could you maybe check the code one more time?

Comment: If you can think of variable `a = 10;` as a box with a label `a` in front and inside it the value `10`, then Promises are easier to understand. Without promises, if you tried `b = fetchSomethingFromTheNetWhichIsSlow()`, then the whole program execution would wait for milliseconds to whole seconds before it can continue (browser would hung). Instead we have Promises.The same slow function can return an empty box with the label `b` in front. The rest of the program that doesn't need the content of `b` can proceed as normal and when the function returns the value, `then(/*run s specific code*/)`.

Comment: Now since this is an exercise and it's meant for you to learn and not give you straight solutions (like I did last time, but that was ok doing it once :), please allow me to leave you with this much, ok? :)
If you think you can figure out the rest, mark this as answered and I'll catch you probably on your next question ;)